# Tried 3 times from scratch, and only get as far as HellowWorld cordova run --device

Tags: linux, apache, cordova, ubuntu

Three times now I have started from absolute scratch and built a Ubuntu 16.04 Virtual Machine right from the install DVD (repartitioned/formatted the drive), updated everything, and followed the instructions on https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ubuntu/index.html to the letter. Each time I get to the HelloWorld step "cordova build --device" and get this...

```
Running command: /home/eq/Downloads/Cordova/helloworld/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build --device
Building Phone Application...

Error: missing armhf chroot
run:
sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-15.04 create
```

Issuing the command "sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-15.04 create" I get

```
A chroot for that name and architecture already exists.
Please see the man-page how to use it.
```

I'd really like to get this to work, but don't know what to do next.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-16.04 create` instead? The tutorial you're following says: "Note that for the latter to work, you will need to have a *corresponding* click chroot installed on your build system." Therefore if you're trying to build Ubuntu 16.04, you might need to use the 16.04 SDK instead of 15.04

Comment: Alternatively, since it sounds like you've already got the 15.04 SDK installed you *could* try `cordova -d build --device -- --framework=ubuntu-sdk-15.04` but it's probably better to stay with the same versions if you can

Comment: Sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on the S.E. related sites, either  http://unix.stackexchange.com or http://askubuntu.com  . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: I give up!  I asked for help and got asked to leave.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you for your reply!

I issued "sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-16.04 create" and here's what I got...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 110, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/bin/click", line 106, in main
    return mod.run(args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click_package/commands/chroot.py",         line 266, in run
return args.func(parser, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click_package/commands/chroot.py", line 65, in create
args.architecture, args.framework, name=args.name, series=args.series)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/click_package/chroot.py", line 320, in __init__
series = framework_series[self.framework_base]
KeyError: 'ubuntu-sdk-16.04'
```

Then I tried cordova -d build --device -- --framework=ubuntu-sdk-15.04

```
No scripts found for hook "before_build".
No scripts found for hook "before_prepare".
Checking config.xml and package.json for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Config.xml and package.json platforms are the same. No pkg.json modification.
Package.json and config.xml platforms are different. Updating config.xml with most current list of platforms.
Failed to require PlatformApi instance for platform "ubuntu". Using polyfill instead.
Checking config.xml for saved plugins that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in ubuntu platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ubuntu platform. Continuing...
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "ubuntu"
No scripts found for hook "after_prepare".
No scripts found for hook "before_compile".
Running command: /home/eq/Downloads/Cordova/helloworld/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build --device --framework=ubuntu-sdk-15.04
Building Phone Application...

Error: missing armhf chroot
run:
sudo click chroot -a armhf -f ubuntu-sdk-15.04 create
Command finished with error code 0: /home/eq/Downloads/Cordova/helloworld/platforms/ubuntu/cordova/build --device,--framework=ubuntu-sdk-15.04
No scripts found for hook "after_compile".
No scripts found for hook "after_build".
```

Comment: This doesn't apparently answer your Q. It should be included as an **edit** to your original Q. Then you can post a comment and include the commentors ID like `@HFB` to ask them to look again. In any case, this is more appropriate on the other forums I have mentioned above. Good luck.